# SQL query and force close challenge

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

here i tried to take name and password from database if the user have already an account, or sign up him by enter his data.

This is the first activity which has force close by clicking on first button to log into the data base

```
public class SelesMeter2Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText ed1;
    EditText ed2;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    SQLiteDatabase sql;
    Cursor c;
    Intent in;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        sql = openOrCreateDatabase("db", 0, null);
        sql.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists "
                + "Employee2 (password integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // log in
        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.bt1) {
            int p = 0;
            String name = ed1.getText().toString();
            String sp = ed2.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Attempt to parse the number as an integer
                p = Integer.parseInt(sp);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // parseInt failed, so tell the user it's not a number
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Sorry, " + sp + " is not a number. Please try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (c.getCount() != 0) {
                c = sql.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    if (name.equals("c.getString(1)") && p == c.getInt(0)) {
                        in = new Intent(this, secondview.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "please sign up first or enter " + "correct data", 2000)
                        .show();
            }

        } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.bt2) {
            // sign up
            Intent in2 = new Intent(this, signup.class);

            startActivity(in2);

        }
    }
}
```

the second class that enter the new user which is not working as expected, 
the toast does not work :

```
public class signup extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText e1;
    EditText e2;
    SQLiteDatabase sql;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singupx);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1s);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2s);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1s);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String n = e1.getText().toString();
        String sp = e2.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Attempt to parse the number as an integer
            int p = Integer.parseInt(sp);
            // This insertion will *only* execute if the parseInt was successful
            // sql.execSQL("insert into Employee2(password,name)values('"+n+"',"+p+")");
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("password", p);
            values.put("name", n);
            sql.insert("Employee2", null, values);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in2 = new Intent(this, secondview.class);
            startActivity(in2);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // parseInt failed, so tell the user it's not a number
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Sorry, " + sp + " is not a number. Please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat trace?

Comment: You need to have the same `sql = openOrCreateDatabase("db", 0, null);` statement in the second activity too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SelesMeter2Activity` you'll have a `NullPointerException` at the line:

```
if (c.getCount() != 0) {
```

as you don't initialize the `Cursor` before that line. Move the query before the above line:

```
c = sql.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);
if (c.getCount() != 0) {
     // ...
```

You should post the exception you get from the logcat.

Also regarding your `signup` activity please don't instantiate the first activity to access fields from it. Open the database again in the `second` activity and insert the values.

Comment: yes you are right :) the error has been gone but the sign up activity does not enter the data into the data base ! the toast does not work

Comment: @SarahAabed At which toast are you referring? Does the signup activity run?

Comment: yes it is run but the toast after the sql query does not work so i guss the data doesnot enter @LuKsprong

Comment: @SarahAabed Did you modify the signup to **NOT** instantiate the `SelesMeter2Activity` activity and instead open the database directly? Have you checked the logcat for any warnings about the insert. Also please consider using a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29 instead of `execSQL` to actually see if the insert goes alright.

Comment: i made the insertion directly from the sign up as you told me now i have to use the insert methode ?

Comment: @SarahAabed Did you solve the problem? You don't see any `Toasts` because you didn't set the `OnClickListener` for the `Button` in the `signup` activity(find the Button in the layout(like you did for the `EditTexts`) and assign the listener `button.setOnClickListener(this);`). Also I recommend that you use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage the database.

Comment: no i still have the null pointer exception...i will try SQLithelper ! ...Luk thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

This is why you are getting error

```
// you are calling the `c.getCount();` before you are assigning
// It will throw null pointer exception
if (c.getCount() != 0) {
    c = sql.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        if (name.equals(c.getString(1)) && p == c.getInt(0)) {
            in = new Intent(this, secondview.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Change the logic like

```
c = sql.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);
c.moveToFirst();
if(!c.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
        if (name.equals(c.getString(1)) && p == c.getInt(0)) {
            in = new Intent(this, secondview.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

and `name.equals("c.getString(1)")` should be `name.equals(c.getString(1))`

**EDIT**

Example of insert method

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("password", n);
values.put("name", p);
database.insert("Employee2", null, values);
```

Comment: yes that is right :) what about the sign up activity it does not accept the data and enter them into the data base

Comment: @SarahAabed Those two classes in the same package?

Comment: @SarahAabed ok, as Luksprog said, change the implementation. I am certain, that the `sql` still not keeping the reference of the database for different context, since you are instantiating new object instead starting it. `onCreate()` which is the entry point of each activity, where you are having the db initialization.

Comment: i have changed the logic and i will try the use the insert methode but did you mean that i have to put it in Oncreate ?Thanks Again :)